# Necesito acceder a los datos de una lista de series de Highchart en C#

Tags: c#, asp, highcharts

Tengo una lista de series Lista_de_Series = new List(); con una coleccion de arreglos d edatos en ella, adicional a esto intento acceder a cada listado en un

foreach (Series var_serie in lista_de_series) { if (var_serie .Name.Equals("PRODUCCION MANUAL")) { 
var_serie.Data

pero no puedo acceder a la coleccion de datos de cada arreglo, no encuentro la manera

Comment: tengo la propiedad var_serie.Data pero no se como iterarla para trabajar con los datos que contienen en ella

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya encontre la respuesta gracias a un foro de Leandro,

```
if (var_serie.Name.Equals("PRODUCCION MANUAL"))
            {
              foreach(var dato in var_serie.Data.ArrayData)
              {
                  double valor = (double)dato;
              }
            }
```

Comment: entonces es la solución o no?

Comment: Si es la solucion, solo que para no abrir otra pregunta y darle continudad al tema pase a un siguiente punto, es valido hacer eso disculpen?

Comment: no, eso no es válido, es necesario que abras una nueva pregunta y des contexto vinculando con esta, pues usar la zona de respuestas para seguir preguntando es mal visto

Comment: Gracias por la aclaracion, una ultima pregunta para el moderador, en ocasiones anteriores he formulado preguntas y me han resuelto, ¿donde puedo dar click para dar como resuelta mi pregunta?

Comment: en el ícono de la palomita que esta a lado izquierdo, aunque aclaro no soy moderador

Answer (score 0):

Si el arreglo de datos se encuentra dentro de cada objeto almacenado en la lista debes de poner un for dentro de tu foreach donde interes el arreglo.

```
Foreach (Series serie in ListaSeries) {
      For(Int i = 0; i < serie.Length ; i++) {
              serie[¡].Data;
      } 
}
```

Algo así, mi ejemplo es algo sencillo pero puedes mejorarlo de acuerdo a tus necesidades.

Comment: por favor deja la edición, así es como se formatea el código

Comment: Gracias por tu colaboracion y tu tiempo Isaac, ahora el siguiente paso es como ubico el dato de determinada posicion n  un arreglo b con respecto a la misma posicion de un dato del arreglo a, necesito hace runa opercion con cada numero de un arrgelo con su par en un segundo arreglo, valga la redundancia

Comment: Tengo en mente ubicar los elemntos por posicion en cada lista pero no se me ocurre como plantearla, alguna sugerencia por favor?